# Throw checked Exception from static block

Tags: java, static-block, checked-exceptions

i want to throw checked exception from a static block, when i tried that the following compilation error arises:

```
error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

my static code block is as follows:

```
static{
if(something)
    doSomething();
else
    throw new Exception("Checked Exception from static block");   

}
```

IF this is not allowed in java, what work around can i do to throw a checked exception from a static block,in other word, how can i do that before the main method is called? thanks.

Comment: Regarding your request of a workaround, there are none that are not hacks.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is : Throwing checked exception from static block is not allowed

Comment: i wanted to post long answer, but then i saw that you marked it as duplicate ... that's why i stopped with the short answer ;-)

Comment: It is allowed if the exception type is unchecked.

Comment: yup ... i was speaking about checked exceptions only